# keep android application landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.example.cap_im"
         android:versionCode="1"
         android:versionName="1.0" 
       >
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>


       <uses-sdk
         android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <activity
          android:name="com.example.cap_im.MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
               android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>

  </manifest>
```

I used above code in android manifest to keep the screen always landscape mode.but it didnt work.above xml file is my manifest file.

Comment: remove  android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: could you post complete manifest file

Comment: Use android:screenOrientation="landscape" line inside activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove configchanges and set this for every activity in manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" 
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **activity** tag you have write like this-

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" 
android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

If you want reflect this for whole app. It should be indside your each and every `activity` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Shani Goriwal and @Tarun Droid. But I think we also need to add the android:config for each activity:

```
 <activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:name="com.example.cap_im.MainActivity">
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this on onCreateview `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`